How to detect the event of execution of specific process on Windows(10)?
I have A.exe and B.exe on Windows 10.
Every time A.exe is executed, I want B.exe to be executed automatically.
How can I develop this feature?
Thanks,
P.S. I prefer node.js, python, Java, Rust, but can learn and write code of other languages/frameworks if that's not too steep.

Rename a.exe to c.exe & make your own a.exe that executes c.exe then b.exe?

That might be also a good solution, but what if I cannot modify the trigger? For example, A.exe is executed by a certain trigger, and I do not have a admin privilege to change it to execute another new program.
